# Calculadora de Juros Compostos em JS

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma calculadora de juros compostos em PHP, onde eu preciso preciso calcular o valor do investimento inicial, o investimento mensal, o período e por porcentagem de juros a cada mês.

A calculadora realiza a soma do valor investido inicialmente + o valor que será investido a cada mês + o juros sobre os dois valores anteriores (juros sobre juros).

Conseguir fazer ela em PHP, mas preciso portar ela pra JavaScript.. porém não entendo quase nada de JS. Baseado em algumas pesquisas, vídeos e no meu código antigo, monte o seguinte código em JS, mas ele não me retorna nada:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Calculadora de Juros Compostos JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculadoras.css">

    <script>
        function calcular_juros_compostos() {
            var investimento_inicial = document.getElementById("investimento_inicial").value;
            var investimento_mensal = document.getElementById("investimento_mensal").value;
            var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
            var taxa_de_juros = document.getElementById("taxa_de_juros").value;

            var investimento_inicial = parseFloat("investimento_inicial");
            var investimento_mensal = parseFloat("investimento_mensal");
            var meses = ("meses");
            var taxa_de_juros = parseFloat("taxa_de_juros");

            var investimento_acumulado = investimento_inicial;

            var total_investimento_acumulado = investimento_inicial + (investimento_mensal * meses);

            var juros_compostos = 0;
            var juros_compostos_total = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < $meses; i++) {
                juros_compostos = (investimento_acumulado + taxa_de_juros) / 100;
                juros_compostos_total += juros_compostos;
                investimento_acumulado += juros_compostos + investimento_mensal;
            }

            var valor_a_receber = total_investimento_acumulado + juros_compostos_total;
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="w-100" method="post" action="">
            <label for="basic-url">Investimento Inicial</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>R$</strong></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" step="0.01" id="investimento_inicial" min="0.00" max="9999999999.00" required>
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url">Investimento Mensal</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>R$</strong></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control currency border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" step="0.01" id="investimento_mensal" min="0.00" max="9999999999.00" required>
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url">Por quanto tempo?</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>&#x1F550</strong></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control currency border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" id="meses" min="1" placeholder="Meses" required>
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url">Juros ao Mês</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <input class="form-control currency border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" step="0.01" id="taxa_de_juros" min="0.01" max="9999999999.00" required>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>%</strong></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular_juros_compostos()">Calcular</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("inicial").innerHTML = investimento_inicial;
            document.getElementById("mensal").innerHTML = investimento_mensal;
            document.getElementById("duracao").innerHTML = meses;
            document.getElementById("tt_investimento").innerHTML = total_investimento_acumulado;
            document.getElementById("juros_recebidos").innerHTML = juros_compostos_total;
            document.getElementById("a_receber").innerHTML = valor_a_receber;
        </script>

        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Investimento Inicial</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="inicial"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Investimento Mensal</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="mensal"><strong>R$</strong><br><small id="juros"></small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Tempo do Investimento</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="duracao"><strong>meses</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Total do Investimento</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="tt_investimento"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Juros Recebidos</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="juros_recebidos"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Valor a Receber c/ Juros</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="a_receber"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá Guilherme eu deu uma olhada no código e achei alguns problemas o primeiro foi que você estava tentando usar as variáveis fora da função **calcular_juros_compostos** no caso depois do form. pois elas não existem fora da função.

O segundo problema foi que sua variável **meses** no for estava com um $ na frente.

fiz as correções e melhorias veja se funciona.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Calculadora de Juros Compostos JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculadoras.css"> -->
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
        function calcular_juros_compostos() {
            let investimento_inicial = parseFloat(document.getElementById("investimento_inicial").value);
            let investimento_mensal =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("investimento_mensal").value);
            var meses = parseInt(document.getElementById("meses").value);
            let taxa_de_juros = parseFloat(document.getElementById("taxa_de_juros").value);

            let investimento_acumulado = investimento_inicial;

            var total_investimento_acumulado = investimento_inicial + (investimento_mensal * meses);
    
            let juros_compostos = 0;
            let juros_compostos_total = 0;

            for (let i = 0; i < meses; i++) {
                juros_compostos = (investimento_acumulado + taxa_de_juros) / 100;
                juros_compostos_total += juros_compostos;
                investimento_acumulado += juros_compostos + investimento_mensal;
            }

            var valor_a_receber = total_investimento_acumulado + juros_compostos_total;

            document.getElementById("inicial").innerHTML = investimento_inicial;
            document.getElementById("mensal").innerHTML = investimento_mensal;
            document.getElementById("duracao").innerHTML = meses;
            document.getElementById("tt_investimento").innerHTML = Number(total_investimento_acumulado).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("juros_recebidos").innerHTML = Number(juros_compostos_total).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("a_receber").innerHTML = Number(valor_a_receber).toFixed(2);


            document.getElementById('formCalc').reset();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="w-100" method="post" id="formCalc" action="">
            <label for="basic-url">Investimento Inicial</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>R$</strong></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" step="0.01" id="investimento_inicial" min="0.00" max="9999999999.00" required>
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url">Investimento Mensal</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>R$</strong></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control currency border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" step="0.01" id="investimento_mensal" min="0.00" max="9999999999.00" required>
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url">Por quanto tempo?</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>&#x1F550</strong></span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control currency border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" id="meses" min="1" placeholder="Meses" required>
            </div>
            <label for="basic-url">Juros ao Mês</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3 rounded-0">
                <input class="form-control currency border border-warning border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" type="number" step="0.01" id="taxa_de_juros" min="0.01" max="9999999999.00" required>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-warning"><strong>%</strong></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="click" value="Calcular" onclick="return calcular_juros_compostos()">Calcular</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Investimento Inicial</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="inicial"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Investimento Mensal</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="mensal"><strong>R$</strong><br><small id="juros"></small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Tempo do Investimento</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="duracao"><strong>meses</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Total do Investimento</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="tt_investimento"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Juros Recebidos</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="juros_recebidos"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Valor a Receber c/ Juros</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="a_receber"><strong>R$</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ivan, mto obrigado pela ajuda. Não sei qual nada de JavaScript.

Poderia me ajudar com uma coisinha? quando eu adiciono a linha "document.getElementById("juros").innerHTML = taxa_de_juros;" para ser mostrado no id="juros" ao executar a calculadora, o navegador em retorna erro 500

Comment: hummm so falando assim fica dificil falar pra você preciso analisar o codigo.